# Get template as string in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say, I have the following single file component in Vue:

```
// Article.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{body}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

After importing this component in another file, is it possible to get its template as a string?

```
import Article from './Article.vue'

const templateString = // Get the template-string of `Article` here.
```

Now `templateString` should contain:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{body}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nop , u will have inside the templateString an object of ur Acticle component. vuejs render to u all the subObject of article component , i mean render,method,data,

Comment: What's the use-case for needing to get the template?  Maybe there's a different way to solve your problem than directly accessing the template.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I'm building a page-builder, where you can drag 'components' onto the page. When the page is done, I want to send the resulting HTML to the server. This way, I only have to define the HTML for the components once (in the Vue components' template).

Comment: Are you using webpack or vite? From what you're saying, you just want the HTML which you can get with `$refs`, but your components won't be reactive or anything, they'll just be pure HTML. So there is a better way to go about this, instead output the component name and use vue with the `runtime-compiler` on the frontend to convert your component's name into actual vue components @Jan-PaulKleemans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible.

> [Under the hood, Vue compiles the templates into Virtual DOM render functions.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)

So your compiled component will have a `render` function, but no place to look at the string that was used to generate it.

> [Vue is not a string-based templating engine](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

However, if you used a string to specify your template, `this.$options.template` would contain the string.

Comment: "It is not possible."

That is not entirely true, you can make a custom loader in webpack using query strings, to import the template as a string like `import html from './component.vue?template=1'`

Answer (score 0):

set ref attribute for your component, and then you can get rendered HTML content of component by using `this.$refs.ComponentRef.$el.outerHTML`, and remember don't do this when created.

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <Article ref="article" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Article from './Article.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      templateString: ""
    }
  },
  components: {
    Article,
  },
  created() {
    // wrong, $el is not exists then
    // console.log(this.$refs.article.$el.outerHTML)
  },
  mounted() {
    this.templateString = this.$refs.article.$el.outerHTML
  },
}
</script>
```